# How to store a clicked URL as a variable to use in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my issue. I want `window.open(TargetLink1[0].href);` to only be activated if the element `alertboxHeader` does not exist, `TargetLink1` is true and on only the page that was opened when I clicked a link. I have successfully done the first two and the issue is with getting, storing or checking for the right url, I don't know where the issue is. This is my code. The URL clicked would as have to be able to be changed if a new URL is clicked.

```
var varurl;
var TargetLink1 = $("a:contains('Accept')")

if ((!document.getElementById('alertboxHeader') && (TargetLink1.length) && (window.location.href.indexOf("" + varurl + "") > -1)  )) {
    window.open(TargetLink1[0].href);
}

function storeurl() {
    var varurl = document.URL;
}

document.onclick = storeurl;
```

Comment: what does console.log(TargetLink1) is showing ?

Comment: i don't know how to use console.log but TargetLink1 grabs the url of a link that contains Accept.

Comment: "on only the page that was opened when I clicked a link" that is really confusing. You want to prevent the link from working based on the current URL? The referral URL? Clicked what link? Huh?

Comment: I'll try to explain it better sorry. Say I click a link that takes me to example.com/1. The function would only be able to run on example.com/1 if it was opened from a clicked link, not typed in.

Comment: So the link only works if page was loaded from another page, not when accessed directly (like from a bookmark or link in email, etc)? Or do you require referring source to be of same origin (same domain) as current page?

Comment: I think you want `document.referrer`

Comment: You sir are correct, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Added answer with two approaches, the second one being less reliable in all browsers but much safer in terms of what you are going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is something like:

```
var validSource = (document.referrer !== "") ? (document.location.href.indexOf(document.referrer) == 0) : false;
```

But be aware that the above compares the document.referrer URL to the current URL as two strings, so that if your referrer were:

```
http://example.org?q=test
```

and the current URL (the link they followed) is:

```
http://example.org/1
```

it would handle it as not matching because of the query string in the referrer URL.

Here's a better way to handle it, using the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) object prototype (which is not necessarily supported in all browsers, but works in Chrome and FF):

```
var referrerOrigin = new URL(document.referrer).origin;
var currentOrigin = document.location.origin;
var validSource = ( referrerOrigin == currentOrigin );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `document.onclick = storeurl;` You should give any id from the document.For Example:

```
document.getElementById("IdHere").onclick = storeurl;
```

Comment: The Id would only work if it was a constant right? The Id can change but the domain is constant.